# Duplicate type name within an assembly in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.0

I have `.NET Core 1.1` API and i am handling the error in startup.cs as below. I am using `Serilog`

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IRequestContext requestContext)
        {      
           loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

           // Ensure any buffered events are sent at shutdown
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(Log.CloseAndFlush);                

            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();

            app.UseExceptionHandler(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Run(
                        async context =>
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                            var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                            if (ex != null)
                            {
                                var errmsg = "An unexpected error has occured in API.";
                                var logDetails = new
                                {
                                    CorrelationId = requestContext.CorrelationId,
                                    Message = errmsg
                                };
                                logger.LogError(1001, ex.Error, "{@LogDetails}", logDetails);
                                await context.Response.WriteAsync(errmsg).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }
                        });
                });

            app.UseMvc();

            logger.LogInformation("Application has started in environment {0}", env.EnvironmentName);
        }
```

Most of the time when there is any exception, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` logs the exception as expected however, *sometimes* i see the following exception in the logs

> 2018-09-21 18:36:01.670 +00:00 [Error] An unhandled exception has
>   occurred: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
>   System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String
>   strTypeName, Type enclosingType)      at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String
>   strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)      at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname,
>   TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder
>   module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder
>   enclosingType)      at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name,
>   TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)      at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyAssembly.DefineType(String
>   name, TypeAttributes attributes, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.GenerateProxyTypeFromProperties(Type
>   sourceType, Type targetType, VerificationResult verificationResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.VerifyProxySupport(ProxyBuilderContext
>   context, Tuple`2 key)      at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.GetProxyType(ProxyTypeCache
>   cache, Type targetType, Type sourceType)      at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyFactory.CreateProxy[TProxy](Object
>   obj)      at Proxy_Method_From_<>f__AnonymousType0`3_To_Void
>   OnBeforeAction(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext,
>   IRouteData)(Object , Object , IProxyFactory )      at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.Write(String
>   diagnosticName, Object parameters)      at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.System.IObserver>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2
>   value)      at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String
>   name, Object value)      at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---      at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()      at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)      at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---      at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()      at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)      at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

So looks like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` its selft throwing exception while logging

**Update 1**

I have the following references. Not sure which reference is causing this issue.
`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` is `2.0` however the only options available for this package are `1.0.*` or `2.*.*`.  I don't see this package has `1.1.*` available

[image]

Comment: Don't mix (ASP).NET Core versions. Don't use packages that are made for 2.0 with 1.x and don't use libraries that only work with 1.1 with 2.x etc.

Comment: see my update 1

Comment: @LP13 , did you found any fix for this?

Comment: if i remember correctly i downgraded `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`  that is compatible with 1.1 version