# Duplicate type name within an assembly in .Net Core 1.1

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1, .net-core-1.1

I am getting the this error every now and then and not exactly pin point what the issue is

I am using .NET Core 1.1 API

> System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String
>   strTypeName, Type enclosingType)    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String
>   strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname,
>   TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder
>   module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder
>   enclosingType)    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name,
>   TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyAssembly.DefineType(String
>   name, TypeAttributes attributes, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.GenerateProxyTypeFromProperties(Type
>   sourceType, Type targetType, VerificationResult verificationResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.VerifyProxySupport(ProxyBuilderContext
>   context, Tuple`2 key)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyTypeEmitter.GetProxyType(ProxyTypeCache
>   cache, Type targetType, Type sourceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.Internal.ProxyFactory.CreateProxy[TProxy](Object
>   obj)    at Proxy_Method_From_<>f__AnonymousType0`3_To_Void
>   OnBeforeAction(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext,
>   IRouteData)(Object , Object , IProxyFactory )    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.Write(String
>   diagnosticName, Object parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.System.IObserver>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2
>   value)    at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name,
>   Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: Step one is to get off 1.1. That version is end of life and unsupported. The current LTS (long term support) release is 2.1, so you need to upgrade to at least that. There's no point in trying to debug this, as it could just be something is fundamentally broken at this point and there is no fix to be had.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution and rebuild it ?Or restart your IIS express and vs to run your project again?

Comment: its not on development machine. Its in production and its random

Comment: It seems that you have the same question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450695/duplicate-type-name-within-an-assembly-in-microsoft-aspnetcore-diagnostics-excep) Do you check your packages version again now?

Comment: ahh..i didnt realize i had the same issue exactly a year before. Thanks for catching that